# Can I display a message when a user wants to start a parameterized build?

Tags: jenkins

I want to display a message to the user when he is about to start a Jenkins build job.

I added the message to the build job description, but the user could also start the job from a view list (where the description is not visible).

Can I add a message to somewhere in the parameters page?

I could use the description field for a parameter, but that's more like a hack, a more prominent position for the message would be good.

Comment: So your objective is to pop-up a message when the user click on "build now"?

Comment: @BrunoLavit yes something like that. But rather than an annoying pop-up maybe a message on the Build Parameters page (since the build is parameterized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the description field a hack? That shows up in the most prominent position - just under the title.

I would just keep it simple and display your message there

Comment: In my version of Jenkins it actually shows under the first parameter field. But I found out that you can format the message with HTML, so I can actually make it to look quite prominent. At the moment I'm going with this solution.